# Android Studio 2.1.1 -> Quick fix not working (and other blue link)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Today, I have install android studio on my mac but i have a problem. I can't use any quick fixes when i click -> nothing ... (sorry i dont know if quick fix is the real name )

EDIT: Is not only quick fixes, other "blue link" don't work too

Such link does not work:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I know how to fix this problem (on the screenshot) but i don't want keep this bug before start dev on my mac.

I use android studio 2.1.1 and java 1.8.0_92 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.5

Someone know how i can fix this problem ? I have look on google but no solution found =(

ps: sorry my English is bad, I hope is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Mac, opt-enter (quick fix) will not work the keyboard input source is set to "Unicode Hex Input".

To remedy, go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources and select a language, such as "U.S.".